# JQuery Deferred. Using $.when and .progress()

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress, jquery-deferred

I am writing a parser littered with Async Tasks.  I use JQuery promises to control and order the async tasks.  This is a psuedo code version of the constructor function:

```
   /**
     * @constructor
     */
    function Parser(json)
    {   
        return $.when(
            this.delete().then(this.insert(json)),
            this.doSomething(),
            this.doSomethingElse().then(this.update(json))
        ) 
    };
```

and this is what an example function looks like:

```
Parser.prototype.doSomething = function()
{   
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    exampleTask(dfd.reject, dfd.resolve);

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

From the JQuery docs:

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when,
>   the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object
>   that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been
>   passed

How can I use .progress() to notify anybody that cares about the overall progress of the Parser? 
 e.g.

```
var parser = new Parser(json);
parser.progress(function(prog){console.log(prog});
```

Heres a fiddle with what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/RjULA/2/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`deferred.notify()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/) to call the `progressCallbacks`. For example:

```
function doSomething() {   
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    var count = 0;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        dfd.notify(count++);
        count > 3 && clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 500);

    return dfd.promise();
};

var promise = doSomething();

promise.progress(function(prog) {
  console.log(prog);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfqJ8/2/).

Comment: I figured out how to use .notify within a function (as in your demo), but I want to pass it back up to the constructor and notify the overall progress from there.  I want to see where the parser is up to overall, not its functions - if you follow me?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: Not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but in that case, you'd need to create and store a reference to the `$.Deferred` in your constructor, so that you can call `notify` within each method. Something along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/B7nzy/

Comment: thats a lot closer!  I thought that if the $.when created a "master" deferred than perhaps I could notify progress directly to that

Comment: @CrimsonChin: `$.when` doesn't create a `$.Deferred` but a `Progress`, that's why you can call `notify` on it. Also note that you *can* accomplish the same thing by passing a simple callback function into the constructor: http://jsfiddle.net/Fubq4/.

Comment: Good point about the callback, perhaps I am overcomplicating it?  Mind you, this is exactly what notify is for.  I have ended up doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/HMStX/7/.  What do you think? - thanks btw

Comment: Looks good! Although someone less familiar with `$.Deferred` might not understand that there's a *master* deferred for notifying progress, and a regular deferred for each task.

Comment: @JoãoSilva "$.when doesn't create a $.Deferred but a **Promise**, that's why you **can't** call notify on it" FTFY